# Documenting setter functions with roxygen

Tags: r, documentation, setter, roxygen, roxygen2

I have a function that does nothing more than ads a unique `attr` to any R object. Base demo:

```
#' Setter function
#' @param x an R object
#' @param value a character value to set
#' @export
`foo<-` <- function(x, value){
    attr(x, 'foo') <- value
    return(x)
}
```

This works like a charm except for generating a good Rd file, relevant part:

```
\usage{
  foo(var, value) <- value
}
```

And of course it triggers a warning while running `R CMD check` as it should be `foo(var) <- value`.

Any hints would be really apprecieted!

---

**Update**: thanks to [richierocks](https://github.com/richierocks) it seems there is a [fix](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues/38#issuecomment-6110935)

Comment: Are you using roxygen or roxygen2?

Comment: @hadley: roxygen2, just added roxygen tag also to attain more attention.

Comment: What version are you using? Roxygen2 should do that automatically since 2.2

Comment: @hadley: I am using 2.2.2 from CRAN. Without `@usage` tag, I get the above result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the roxygen tag `@usage`

Here is an example from one of my packages:

```
#' @rdname pattern
#' @usage pattern(x) <- value
#' @param value New value
#' @export pattern<-
"pattern<-" <- function(x, value=c("^", "($|(_\\d+(_\\d+)*)$)")){
  attr(x, "pattern") <- value
  x
}
```

---

This results in my desired documentation:

```
Usage

  pattern(x) <- value

Arguments
x surveydata object

value New value
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks @Andrie for pointing my attention to `@usage` - I just do not how could I take no notice of this useful tag.

Comment: That's because you should never need to use `@usage` - any time you do it is a bug in roxygen2 and you should file a bug report.

Comment: Thanks @hadley, I have added a comment on the [appropriate issue](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues/38#issuecomment-3516591).