# Assignment function documentation fails R CMD CHECK

Tags: r, roxygen2

I'm having trouble with `check`ing assignment functions with Roxygen.

Here's a fairly minimal example:

```
#' Get sp feature IDs
#' @aliases IDs IDs.default IDs.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame IDs<- IDs<-.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
#' @param x The object to get the IDs from or assign to
#' @param value The character vector to assign to the IDs
#' @param \dots Pass-alongs
#' @author Ari B. Friedman
#' @rdname IDs
IDs <- function(x,...) {
  UseMethod("IDs",x)
}
#' @method IDs default
#' @S3method IDs default
#' @rdname IDs
IDs.default <- function(x,...) {
  stop("Currently only SpatialPolygonsDataFrames are supported.")
}
#' @method IDs SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
#' @S3method IDs SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
#' @rdname IDs
IDs.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame <- function(x,...) {
  vapply(slot(x, "polygons"), function(x) slot(x, "ID"), "")
}

#' Assign sp feature IDs
#' @rdname IDs
"IDs<-" <- function( x, value ) {
  UseMethod("IDs<-",x)
}
#' @method IDs<- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
#' @S3method IDs<- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
#' @rdname IDs
"IDs<-.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame" <- function( x, value) {
  spChFIDs(x,value)
}
```

And when I run `check`:

```
* checking for code/documentation mismatches ... WARNING
Codoc mismatches from documentation object 'IDs':
IDs<-
  Code: function(x, value)
  Docs: function(x, value, value)
IDs<-.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
  Code: function(x, value)
  Docs: function(x, value, value)
```

I don't understand where the second `value` is coming from.  I've tried eliminating the `@param value` on the theory that maybe Roxygen automatically creates an entry for assignment functions, but that doesn't eliminate the `(x,value,value)` definition and produces a new warning complaining that I haven't defined `value`.

Here's the relevant portion of the `.Rd` generated:

```
\usage{
  IDs(x, ...)

  \method{IDs}{default} (x, ...)

  \method{IDs}{SpatialPolygonsDataFrame} (x, ...)

  IDs(x, value) <- value

  \method{IDs}{SpatialPolygonsDataFrame} (x, value) <-
    value
}
```

I don't see the `(x, value, value)` signature that `check` claims is there.

This is an S3 function but it's operating on a S4 object.  That should still make it S3, I think.  But if not it might be that my use of `@S3method` is the problem.

Help?

Comment: It's probably because S4 support in roxygen2 sucks :( You can try the experimental [roxygen3](http://github.com/hadley/roxygen3/) which will be merged back into roxygen2 at some point in the future.

Comment: This seems to be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873514/documenting-setter-functions-with-roxygen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a rather hackish way to go about it but it appears that the way roxygen handles this is still broken for the time being ([LINK](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues/38)).  But you can manually add the usage section into your roxygen comments directly.

```
#' Assign sp feature IDs
#' @rdname IDs
#' @usage IDs(x) <- value
"IDs<-" <- function( x, value ) {
    UseMethod("IDs<-",x)
}

#' @method IDs<- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
#' @S3method IDs<- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
#' @rdname IDs
#' @usage IDs(x) <- value
"IDs<-.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame" <- function( x, value) {
    spChFIDs(x,value)
}
```