# Multiple functions in one .Rd file

Tags: r, documentation, package, roxygen, roxygen2

**Short version**: Can I emulate the documentation of `Normal` in package `stats` using `roxygen`?

**Long version**: I'm working on a package and was trying make the documentation more readable by having a number of functions with common inputs/parameters collected under one heading, which will be a generic reference to the group. Each function should still be available to the end user independently.

I took as inspiration the documentation for `Normal` which gives a number of methods related to the normal distribution e.g. `stats::dnorm()`.

When I search `?dnorm` I find the name of the help section is `Normal` even though `Normal` does not appear to be an exported function or object.

What I've tried is putting the following into `funs.R`:

```
##' @rdname funs
##' @name funs
##' @aliases sum1
##' @aliases prod1
##' @title Two functions
##' @param x X
##' @param y Y
##' @return sum1 returns x+y
##' \cr
##' prod1 returns x*y
##' @examples
##' sum1(3,4)
##' prod1(3,4)
##' @export
sum1 <- function(x,y) x+y
##' @export
##' @rdname funs
prod1 <- function(x,y) x*y
```

I then run `roxygen2` on the above.
The difficulty is that when running `R CMD check` on this minimal package, it finds the package cannot be loaded as `undefined exports: funs`. 
If I remove the line `##' @name funs` the package passes `R CMD check` but the name of the help section is `sum1` rather than `funs`.
If I add the following below the examples section:

```
##' @export
funs <- function(x) x
```

It passes and I can see the help formatted as I would like, but I'm exporting a meaningless function in order to get the name to display correctly.

I tried looking in the source help files for `stats` to see how it was achieved, but they are in `.Rdx` format which I'm not sure how to display.

Also, on a related note, does what sort of thing *is* `Normal`?

```
require(stats)
getAnywhere("Normal")
> no object named 'Normal' was found
```

---

**Update:**

@TylerRinker - I'm afraid this was the first thing I had tried. This combines the functions into one `.Rd` file but the name of the associated help is the same as the name of the first function, which is what I was trying to avoid:

```
##' sum
##' gives the sum
##' @param x X
##' @param y Y
##' @return sum1 returns x+y
##' @examples
##' sum1(3,4)
##' @rdname funs
##' @export
sum1 <- function(x,y) x+y
##' product
##' gives the product
##' @return prod1 returns x*y
##' @examples
##' prod1(3,4)
##' @rdname funs
##' @export
prod1 <- function(x,y) x*y
```

@Andrie - this solution causes exactly the same difficulty, the name of the help is the same as the first function.

Perhaps this just isn't possible...

Comment: I may be wrong but this is how I handle this: https://github.com/trinker/reports/blob/master/R/GQ.R

Comment: Remove `##' @name funs` and it should work (I think).

Comment: Relevant post from [Hadley](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html#dry2), use of `@describeIn` option.

Comment: For Future Googlers: Check out  https://gist.github.com/jefferys/b79fe87314b0dc72fec9

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is the best workaround I've found, but will be glad to change accepted answer if something better comes along...

```
##' @name funs
##' @aliases sum1
##' @aliases prod1
##'
##' @title Two functions of x and y
##'
##' @param x =X
##' @param y =Y
##'
##' @note \code{funs} is a generic name for the functions documented.
##' \cr
##' If called, \code{funs} returns its own arguments.
##'
##' @rdname funs
##' @export
funs <- function(x,y) {identity(c(x,y))}
##'
##' @rdname funs
##' @return \code{sum1(x,y)} returns x+y
##' @examples
##' sum1(3,4)
##' @export
sum1 <- function(x,y) x+y
##'
##' @rdname funs
##' @return \code{prod1(x,y)} returns x*y
##' @examples
##' prod1(3,4)
##' @export
prod1 <- function(x,y) x*y
```

Note that formatting avoids the use of `@usage` in order to avoid making this [a reportable bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873514/documenting-setter-functions-with-roxygen).

I can see how this may have been better addressed on [github](https://github.com/hadley/roxygen3).

A better solution which does use `@usage` is to add the following line:

```
##' @usage funs(x,y) A nominal function of x and y
```

after the first use of

```
##' @rdname funs
##' @export
```

However I'm trying to minimize the no. of warnings thrown by `R CMD check` in order to placate the powers that be, in particular the folloiwng:

```
 Functions with \usage entries need to have the appropriate \alias
    entries, and all their arguments documented.
    The \usage entries must correspond to syntactically valid R code.
```

This last may be an error of my reading of documentation for `@usage`.

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't think you need @aliases, those will be added automatically with @rdname funs. Second, @usage must contain only R code, so if you want to add a comment, put it after a comment `##' @usage funs(x,y) # A nominal function of x and y`

Comment: I see how this works for functions. How would one modify it for data sets?

Comment: @jebyrnes, I explore that for datasets, the only problem I found is that only the first "@format" is taken into account.

Answer (score 29):

As far as I understand, the only way to have 3 names documented in your .Rd file is to document 3 actual objects as you did. But the trick is: one of them can be `NULL` and not exported!

```
##' @name funs
##' @rdname funs
##'
##' @title Two functions of sum1 and prod1
##'
##' @param x =X
##' @param y =Y
##'
##' @return x*y (prod1) or x+y (sum1).
NULL

##' @rdname funs
##' @examples
##' sum1(3,4)
##' @export
sum1 <- function(x,y) x+y

##' @rdname funs
##' @examples
##' prod1(3,4)
##' @export
prod1 <- function(x,y) x*y
```

It looks quite hacky, but it works.